# Arbitrary number of arguments in printf(). What is this called in C programming?

Tags: c

When we use `printf()` with varying number of arguments like

```
printf("Hello");

printf("%d",a);

printf("%d%d",b,c);
```

why is this not called "overloading" (using same method with different task perform)?
If it is overloading, then why is C not considered an object-oriented programming language?

Comment: printf is a function, not a method. A method is a function of a Class. Classes are a Concept of “Object-Oriented Programming” Languages. C does only have structs, but you can program with object-oriented Concepts in C.

Comment: You can use this feature via `stdarg.h`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), not an overload. Overloading has nothing to do with object orientation.

Answer (score 3):

> why is this not called "overloading"

Because you're using **the same function**:

```
int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);
```

One prerequisite for overloading is to have different functions / methods named the same. Here we just have **one function**, albeit very versatile thanks to the varargs feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's not method overloading. It just happens that [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) receives an optional [`vargs`](http://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) as the second argument, that is, a variable arguments list.

> int printf ( const char * format, ... );
>
> Print formatted data to
> stdout Writes to the standard output (stdout) a sequence of data
> formatted as the format argument specifies. After the format
> parameter, the function expects at least as many additional arguments
> as specified in format.

Answer (score 0):

Object-oriented programming refers to a paradigm that includes encapsulation, message passing, inheritance, and polymorphism. In other words, OO means defining a `class` with `virtual` functions that are *overridden*. That's different from *overloading*, which is to perform different actions in a function based on the types of the parameters.

What `printf()` does is neither *overloading* nor *overriding*. It's a variable-length argument list.